# How can i connect the body to the hand?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, mirror

Im pretty new in Blender and this is one of my first modeled characters.I'm trying to figure out how to Connect body to hand, but I don´t know how.

The body and hand are both joined (and they have Mirror modifier added) but every time a try to connect them with *Bridge Edge Loops* it makes something horrible... see picture 2.

[image: This is what i am trying to connect together][image: This is error what i get :(]

Comment: It looks to me like you have the unmirrored parts of opposite sides, e.g. the right hane and the left part of the body. Click the eye icon in the modifier to disable it and see if that is the case. Possibly post an image of it, or upload your blend-file to {Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and include the link in your question. The normals of the body seem to be pointing inwards as well.

Answer (score 2):

Like Duane Dibbley is saying you are having the hand on the wrong side.
Try to attach the hand on the other side or enable 'Adjust Edit Cage' in the Mirror modifier:

[image]

Comment: I would say it's better to actually turn *off* Mirror modifier in Edit mode in order to see where real geometry is. Then it should be easy to move parts of mesh as needed.

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this situations is:

1. **Join the two meshes** -> Select the two meshes and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
2. Go to **Edit Mode**
3. **Select each vertex** and merge them with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>
4. Select the merge you like